# cp between mounts using tar (does drive A have to have free space equal to filesize) to complete tar process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

Does the following command if issued between two drives require that the current drive have enough space to accommodate everything being moved to the second drive?

```
    tar cvf - .* --exclude=\. --exclude=\.\. | (cd /dest/dir; tar xvf -)
```

My line of thinking is that the tar has to be created on drive A before being moved to drive B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The tar "file" exists only in the pipeline; it's not written to disk in the intermediate stage, but only at the destination when you extracted it.